# Creating a function to ask user for a file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to make function which asks the user for a filename. If the file is not found, it will keep asking. This what I have please help..

```
def return_text_file(infile):
    while infile:

        try:
            file = open(infile)
        except IOError:

            print("Could not find the file specified")
            infile = input ("Enter the file name")
    return open_infile
```

```
file_input = input ("Enter the file name")
return_text_file(file_input)
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? One thing I can think of is that you did not have a `break` statement in that while loop

Comment: The first thing that jump out at me is that you are returning open_infile - something not previously defined

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function (e.g. `ask_file_name` below) to get a valid answer from the user. It will repeat constantly until an existing name is given.

```
import os

path_str = '/home/userblabla/ProjectBlabla/'


def ask_file_name():
    files_detected = os.listdir(path_str)

    while True:
        print('\nFiles:')
        for file in files_detected:
            print(file)

        file_name_given = input('\nFile name?')
        if file_name_given not in files_detected:
            print("Could not find the file specified")

        else:
            print('Thanks friend.')
            return file_name_given

my_file_name = ask_file_name()

with open(my_file_name, 'r') as opened_file:
    # Do stuff on opened_file
    ......
```

`with open()` automatically closes the file, and it might be better if you use it instead of `open()`.